# mysql prepared statements which statement i should use

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Is there any major difference between the following prepared statements?  Which one is more preferred, if so why?

1:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(userName) VALUES (:user)");
$user = "Steve";
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
$stmt->execute();
```

2:

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare('INSERT into users(userName) VALUES(:user)');
$stmt2->execute(array(':user'=>'Steve'));
```

Comment: The only difference is that `bindParam` can bind "output parameters" if you are using a stored procedure that returns value(s).  Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: A difference from 1 to 2 is that 1 allows for any user ($user) to be specified if that code where in a function, version 2 is hard coded. Personally I prefer 1 as I come from the verbose coding style camp - but terse coding is okay also, so long as its readable and commented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bindParam` takes a variable parameter as a **reference**. That means variable value MIGHT be modified, depending on what you did (like invoked a stored procedure that alters value of variables passed to it).

That's why you should be using `bindValue` instead, unless you expect MySQL to alter the value of your variable.

Only actual MAJOR difference is that you cannot specify the variable type if you use your second scenario. Every parameter is treated as a string, while when using `bindParam` / `bindValue`, you have the freedom to define whether the parameter is a string or integer.

So what you should use then? Well, neither is wrong. If you find it easier to use second approach while  inserting a lot of string data, then there's nothing wrong with it.